# Como comparar strings diferenciando maiúsculas de minúsculas?

Tags: c#, string

Tenho seguinte código:

```
Usuarios user = DataModel.Usuarios.Where(x => x.Login.Equals(login,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && x.Senha.Equals(senha,StringComparison.Ordinal)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Gostaria de obter o seguinte resultado:

```
"login" == "Login" |true|
"senha" == "Senha" |false|
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ao passar o parâmetro `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` você está informando para não diferenciar entre maiúsculas de minúsculas, logo:

```
login == Login // Será verdadeiro se o parâmetro for informado
```

Mas como pode ver, apesar da palavra ser a mesma, o que diferencia uma da outra é a *case-sensitive*, veja esse exemplo:

```
string a = "email@email.com";
string b = "Email@email.com";
    
// Ira retornar Falso, porque não foi informado
// para ignorar case-sensitive
if (a.Equals(b)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Verdadeiro");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Falso");
}
    
// OrdinalIgnoreCase
// Ira retorna Verdadeiro, porque foi informado
// para ignorar case-sensitive
if (a.Equals(b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Verdadeiro");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Falso");
}
```

> Veja funcionando no [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8kwNak)

#### Referência

- [Enumeração StringComparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 8):

Você está comparando a senha da seguinte maneira:

```
x.Senha.Equals(senha, StringComparison.Ordinal)
```

Segundo a documentação o `StringComparison.Ordinal` faz a comparação case-sensitive, ou seja, considerando maiúsculas e minúsculas.

Quando você está comparando o usuário, está fazendo assim:

```
x.Login.Equals(login, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Não sei a necessidade do uso do `OrdinalIgnoreCase` no seu caso. Eu sempre utilizo o `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` para esse fim, desta forma:

```
x.Login.Equals(login, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Se puder, vale a leitura de "[Difference between InvariantCulture and Oridinal string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492799/difference-between-invariantculture-and-ordinal-string-comparison)".

O código que você postou já faz o que você quer. Isso *evalua*:

```
"login" == "Login" > true (é case-insensitive)
"senha" == "Senha" > false (é case-sensitive)
```

Answer (score 7):

Você pode usar a propriedade [InvariantCultureIgnoreCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.stringcomparer.invariantcultureignorecase(v=vs.110).aspx) da classe `StringComparer`, veja:

```
string str1 = "Stack";
string str2 = "stack";

Console.WriteLine(str1.Equals(str2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
Console.WriteLine(str1.Equals(str2));
```

Saída:

> True
>   False

Veja funcionando no [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hbGwn8).

Comment: Mas o AP perguntou como diferenciar maiúsculas de minúsculas. O `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` não faz o contrário?

Comment: @vnbrs pelo que eu entendi é para ignorar o case-sensitive, a função acima faz isso, e a debaixo não ignora o case-sensitive.